# Javascript Redirect Based on a Form Selection (Before Submitting)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect, hubspot

I am looking to redirect users to a different page (for an academic account) based on them making that selection in a Hubspot form field. This ideally would happen onchange and occur as soon as it is selected instead of happening on a form submission.

**ID:** license_type_of_interest-cb1da23a-da50-42f8-b281-b8845c18b0a6
**value:** Academic License

Attempted to get it by Id, match the values to "Academic License" and if that is the value to redirect to a new url immediately. Also, unfortunately using Wordpress and Hubspot forms.

**Select Snippet:**

```html
<select id="license_type_of_interest-cb1da23a-da50-42f8-b281-b8845c18b0a6" required="" class="hs-input" name="license_type_of_interest">
  <option disabled="" value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="Silver License">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold License">Gold</option>
  <option value="Enterprise License">Enterprise</option>
  <option value="Academic License">Academic</option>
  <option value="Researcher License">Researcher</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please share code snippets of what you have tried already and explain how it did not work!

Comment: Just use links. Please. There are all sorts of negative usability and accessibility implications with trying to use a select element as a navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
const licences = {
  "Silver License" : "silver.html",
  "Gold License": "gold.html",
  ...
  "Researcher License": "researcher.html"
};
document.querySelector("[id^='license_type_of_interest']") // a select with ID starting with 'license_type_of_interest'
  .addEventListener("change", function() { // when changed
    const val = this.value;
    if (val) location = licenses[val]; // redirect to URL in object
  })
```